# What does `i` in `token.i+1` mean when using a token returned by spacy's Language?

Tags: python, spacy

```
from spacy.language import Language

@Language.component("CustomB")
def set_custom_boundaries(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text == ';':
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = True
    return doc
nlp.add_pipe("CustomB",before="parser")
```

All I need to know is what does **i+1** do in this code:

```
doc[token.i+1]
```

knowing that `i` is not defined in the function, neither as an index nor as a simple variable.

Comment: It's not `i+1`. Read it as `(token.i) + 1`. I don't know what type of object `token` is, but it seems it is an object with an `i` attribute, that is a number, then add 1 to it.

Comment: For debugging, print out `type(token)` and `token.i`. The type should hopefully help you find the docs for that object type and hopefully also lead you to `i`.

Comment: This is an operator precedence quesiton.  "dot" binds much higher than `+`.  Just like `3+4*5` gets parsed as `3+(4*5)`, in this case `token.i+1` is parsed as `(token.i)+1`.

Comment: oh okay thank you so much it was very useful comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is not a seperate variable. It is an attribute of `token`. And notice that it is not `i+1` but instead it is `token.i + 1`. `i` is from the `token` object. First python gets the value of `i` from `token` then it increases it by one.

Consider the example below:

```
class X:
    i = 10

token = X()

print(token.i+1) # it is in fact (token.i) + 1 so result is: 11
```

If you have any question please ask.

Comment: Your example is `i` as a class variable. It can also be an instance variable or even a property.

Comment: so **i** here is  an index for a each value in doc as (token)

Comment: now I understand, or at least i know how to work with it thank you bro

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes you are right. This is just an example for learning purposes. Because there was no clarification on what `token` is I wanted to show an example.

Comment: @HadiMonzer Your welcome my friend. I encourage you to try to understand it with some examples. It helps you to get better at coding and code even faster.

Answer (score 2):

The function accepts a `Doc` type: https://spacy.io/api/doc/#init

In this section:

```
for token in doc[:-1]:
    if token.text == ';':
        doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = True
```

- Iterate the 'tokens' of the doc: https://spacy.io/api/token except the last (`:-1`)
- If the text of the token is a semi-colon, take the index of the current token `token.i+1` and set the attribute "is_sent_start" to `True`.
  from the doc:

  > `i`: The index of the token within the parent document